# How to Escape Character in EL with JSTL tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have this JSP code snippet:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${var1.properties[\"Item Type\"] eq \"Animal's Part\"}">
    <c:set var="cssClassName" value="animalpart" />
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="cssClassName" value="" />
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The JSP cannot be compiled by the server. However, if I remove the character "'" from "Animal's Part", it is compilable. I tried to escape it by using "\" character but it still gives me error.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated. I tried to avoid using scriptlet if possible.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I managed to get it working (after posting to StackOverflow), posted as one of the solution in this question. I tried other solution posted before that (by Vincent and Eddie), however, unfortunately, none works in my environment, although I reckon that they might works in the answers' environment. Thanks.

Comment: In which environ Eddie's/Vincent's solution didn't work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the solution that works in my use case:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:set var="itemType"        value="${var1.properties[\"Item Type\"]}" />
<c:set var="item_animalpart" value="Animal's Part" />
<c:set var="item_treepart"   value="Tree's Part" />

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${itemType eq name_item_animalpart}">
    <c:set var="cssClassName" value="animalpart" />
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${itemType eq name_item_treepart}">
    <c:set var="cssClassName" value="treepart" />
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="cssClassName" value="" />
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: **item_animalpart** and **item_treepart** are redundant definitions

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<c:when test='${var1.properties["Item Type"] eq "Animal\'s Part"}'>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two easy choices:

```
<c:when test="${var1.properties['Item Type'] eq 'Animal\'s Part'}">

<c:when test='${var1.properties["Item Type"] eq "Animal\'s Part"}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escapeXml="false"
For example:

```
<c:out value="${formulario}" escapeXml="false" />
```